# Is there a way to find out which app has the camera locked?

Tags: android, android-camera

In our app we're using camera to scan QR codes. I got a few crashes on the dev console saying "fail to connect to camera service". Reading around I found out it is possible that another app has the camera opened and didn't call release() onPause (I tested this is possible with a simple app that behaves like this). I already made an error message for the user instead of crash however I'd like to point the user to the app that is blocking access to camera. Is something like this possible or the best I can do is "please exit any applications that might be using the camera and try again"?

Comment: Just release camera service and re-open it

Comment: How can I release something that I don't have locked? To clarify I have our app and then a simple test app that has two buttons - one calls mCamera = Camera.open() and the other mCamera.release(). I open the test app, lock/open the camera and then open our app (completely different app) and try to access the camera and it fails. I can't call mCamera.release() in our app because mCamera is null (since mCamera = Camera.open() failed).

Comment: Then you could throws the Exception and show error to user for closing camera intent but it seems not possible to show which application is currently using camera service

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have now. I was just wondering if I can be more specific than just "some app is using the camera". thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to Help :) Best luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible.

Comment: yeah it seems like it, I'm marking this as answer since, unfortunately, it is.